# What is this broad-leaved ground plant?

Tags: identification

This plant is low to the ground, thriving in the shade, and seems to have a soft stem rather than a woody stalk. It's growing near my front steps rather aggressively and I am concerned it might be invasive. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the leaves on this are large (about a foot in length if old), then you're looking at burdock. This isn't invasive unless you allow it to go to seed. The flowers are actually kind of attractive in a thistle-y sort of way, but the seeds stick to fabric and can be literally a pain. It's easy enough to dig out, especially now; later on, you may break its taproot, but it is rare for the plant to come back from that.

Personally, I'd remove it ASAP.

Please let me know if the leaves are tiny and I'll delete this answer as being incorrect.

Comment: yes, the leaf in the picture is about 14 inches long